# AWS CodeCommit With Multi-factor Authentication. Keep getting fatal: unable to access .. The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, multi-factor-authentication

### What's the Problem?

My IAM User has two policies: **AdministratorAccess** and **ForceMultiFactorAuthentication**. When **ForceMultiFactorAuthentication** policy is attached, from the Windows command-line, I get 403 errors when trying to do anything to the repository (ex: `git clone ..`). When I remove the policy, I can work with the repo (ex: `git clone` works).

### My Question

Is there something about my **ForceMultiFactorAuthentication** policy that is preventing codecommit from working? How do I properly setup CodeCommit with Multi-factor authentication?

### General Recreation Steps

1. Create an IAM user group named "Admins" with AdministratorAccess and ForceMultiFactorAuthentication permissions
2. Create a non-root IAM user
3. Add non-root IAM user to "Admins" group
4. Logged in as non-root IAM user, on Security Credentials tab, setup MFA auth (scan QR code, etc.), AND create HTTPS Git credentials for AWS CodeCommit
5. Create a repo in CodeCommit
6. From command-line, attempt `git clone https://git-codecommit...` locally
7. Command-line returns `fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit...': The requested URL returned error: 403`
8. My non-root IAM user removes **ForceMultiFactorAuthentication** policy from "Admins" group
9. `git clone ..` and it clones the repo. It works.

### Doesn't make sense because...

My IAM user has **AdministratorAccess**. Plus, policy summary shows CodeCommit has full access to all resources.

---

My **ForceMultiFactorAuthentication** policy is below (and is very similar to [AWS-provided one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_my-sec-creds-self-manage.html)):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowViewAccountInfo",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnPasswords",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ChangePassword",
                "iam:GetUser"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnAccessKeys",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateAccessKey",
                "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:UpdateAccessKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnSigningCertificates",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteSigningCertificate",
                "iam:ListSigningCertificates",
                "iam:UpdateSigningCertificate",
                "iam:UploadSigningCertificate"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnSSHPublicKeys",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:UpdateSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:UploadSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnGitCredentials",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:DeleteServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
                "iam:ResetServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:UpdateServiceSpecificCredential"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnVirtualMFADevice",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnUserMFA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAllExceptListedIfNoMFA",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:GetUser",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                "sts:GetSessionToken",
                "iam:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following section in your `ForceMultiFactorAuthentication` policy deny `all` requests (except the actions mentioned in the `NotAction` section) that are not authenticated using MFA

```
{
            "Sid": "DenyAllExceptListedIfNoMFA",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:GetUser",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                "sts:GetSessionToken",
                "iam:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
        }
```

With `HTTPS GIT credentials`, you are authenticating to the CodeCommit repository using the username & password. There is no usage of session token (basically MFA code). So it is not possible to validate MFA for authentication. As a result your request is denied. Similar is the case with SSH key pair authentication for CodeCommit.

To fix this you can add required `codecommit` actions in the `NotAction` list of the policy. You need to include `kms` actions as well. Because data in CodeCommit repositories is encrypted in transit and at rest. So permission required for encrypt and decrypt actions while you are  performing clone, pull or push activities from/to repos.

The following policy fix your CodeCommit 403 error.

```
{
            "Sid": "DenyAllExceptListedIfNoMFA",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:GetUser",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                "sts:GetSessionToken",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "codecommit:GitPull",
                "codecommit:GitPush",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext",
                "kms:DescribeKey"

            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
        }
```

Since you have already attached Administrator access policy to your user, you don't require the entire content of ForceMultiFactorAuthentication policy. The above policy is sufficient. If you want to enable the MFA restriction for all IAM users(non-admin users), use entire content of your policy attach it to users.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. I removed `kms:ReEncrypt` from solution. I believe the above policy is sufficient. Check whether you can perform all the Git operations with the above policy. if you receive any further error related to `kms` try add the `kms:ReEncryptFrom` & `kms:ReEncryptFrom` and check

Comment: I just tested. For my use-case, having the 2 codecommit pull/push actions, `kms:Encrypt` and `kms:Decrypt` was sufficient. The other `kms` actions didn't affect me yet, but if I encounter issues, I'll try them adding them in the future!